# 'UITableViewCell' does not have a member named 'nameLabel'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

### I'm using a custom nib to load into a UITableView and trying to access the custom labels - but can't seem to get them to find the member!  What am I doing wrong?

updated code 15/4 for completeness

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = 80

// registered the nib  
var cellNib = UINib(nibName: "IndividualResultCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier:     
                                          "IndividualResultCell")

    self.monthView = [

    Month(name: "Darren Jensen", salesrev: 15000, gp: 5000,  
          gppercent: 33.3),
    Month(name: "Duncan Lane", salesrev: 17500, gp: 5000, 
          gppercent: 28.6)]

     // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
       }

    // downcast the cell to the custom class
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
      ("IndividualResultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
        UITableViewCell

    let month = self.monthView[indexPath.row]

    // Error message here ... nameLabel not a member of UITableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel?.text = month.name
    cell.salesrevLabel?.text = month.salesrev

    return cell
}
```

----  the custom class

```
import UIKit

  class IndividualResultCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var salesrevLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gpLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gppercentLabel: UILabel!

 }
```

IndividualResultCell.xib - have checked the reuse identifier - it is IndividualResultCell

Comment: show your code where you call registerClass for the custom cell.

Answer (score 3):

You need to downcast the cell to your custom class:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IndividualResultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IndividualResultCell
    ...
}
```

Assuming that you assigned the class to the prototype cell in InterfaceBuilder or registered the class properly if you do that in code.

Answer (score 0):

Register your NIB in the viewDidLoad function first...

```
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "IndividualResultCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "IndividualResultCell")
    }
```

Then try to dequeue the custom cell like this...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IndividualResultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IndividualResultCell
```

EDIT 1 - Array Definition
Regarding your comment below, I assume you have Month defined somthing like this in your code...

```
class Month  {
var name = String()
var salesrev = Int()
var gp = Int()
var gppercent = Double()
}
```

I would then define your array like this and see if that fixes the problem you have populating your tableview cell.  The problem where the println command shows you are returning an unexpected value from the array.

```
var monthView : Array = []

var theMonth = Month()
theMonth.name = "Darren Jensen"
theMonth.salesrev = 15000
theMonth.gp = 5000
theMonth.gppercent = 33.3

monthView.append(theMonth)

theMonth.name = "Duncan Lane"
theMonth.salesrev = 17500
theMonth.gp = 5000
theMonth.gppercent = 28.6

monthView.append(theMonth)
```

Comment: Still stuck. Have assigned the prototype cell in interface builder to IndividualResultCell and thought I had downcast the cell to the custom class.

Comment: That is strange I have a similar setup for an app and it works fine.  So you are getting the error: "nameLabel not a member of IndividualResultCell" now right?  Do you have the IBOutlet connected in the NIB file correctly?

Comment: I think so. I wrote up the IBOutlets in the IndividualResultCell class then from the label in the nib I control dragged to the respective outlet in the class to connect up.  The connections manager appears to be linked.

Comment: After the statement: "let month = self.monthView[indexPath.row]" printout the value of month with a println statement : println("Month value \\(month)")    Is this the Month Name value as a string you are expecting?

Comment: Added the println - and got the following ... Month value DailySales.Month Was expecting members of the Array 'Month'  e.g.. Darren Jensen. Commenting out the problem line cell.nameLabel.text = month.name I do get the nib loaded into the simulator - but only with the placeholder names.

Comment: I just updated the answer above with EDIT 1, see if that improves things.